# Button created doesn't have onclick

Tags: javascript

Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>BookInc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body style="background-color:white;">

    <div id= "mainPage">

    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my javascript:

```
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = "button";
btn.className = "btn";
btn.value = "Negociate";
btn.onclick = console.log("hello");
document.getElementById('mainPage').appendChild(btn);
```

When my button is created the onclick event is fired automatically (I get hello printed in the console without clicking on the button) and then doesn't work.
When I inspected the page I realized that my button didn't have an onclick anymore (just class and value)

I can't figure out why so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onclick` needs to be a function. Please see the example.

```js
var sayHello = function(){
    console.log("hello");
};

var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = "button";
btn.className = "btn";
btn.value = "Negociate";
btn.onclick = sayHello;
document.getElementById('mainPage').appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>BookInc</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body style="background-color:white;">

    <div id= "mainPage">

    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work like that but then why doesn't it work if I create a function and try to pass it in like this:

function test(){
 console.log("hello");
}

var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = "button";
btn.className = "btn";
btn.value = "Negociate";
btn.onclick = test();
document.getElementById('mainPage').appendChild(btn);

Comment: @Gobhniu What you are trying does not work because you are "calling" the function. `onclick` is expecting you to "define" the function.

Comment: @Gobhniu OK. I see what you are saying. I updated the answer. You may define the function elsewhere, but you need to set `onclick` to that definition. When you put the `()` like `test()` it is calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

btn.onclick requires a callback, you need to supply a function/arrow function for this to work. Currently, your code prints "hello" exactly once, namely at the momment it is loaded. To execute it when the button is pressed you need to supply a callable function like this:

```
btn.onclick = () => console.log("hello);
```